# manipulated images with corresponding ground-truth masks

Tags: python, image

I am reading this paper about image manipulation detection [Hybrid LSTM and Encoder-Decoder Architecture for Detection of Image Forgeries](https://vcg.engr.ucr.edu/sites/g/files/rcwecm2661/files/2019-03/TIP_2019.pdf)

and I am trying to recreate it myself, but I am still a beginner in machine learning  and I just reached section *3.1.1 Resampling Features* and figure 3 caught my eye.

[image]

> Fig. 3. (a) Examples of manipulated images from the NIST dataset. (b)
>   Corresponding ground-truth masks for the manipulated images in column
>   (a), green for non-manipulated patches and red for manipulated ones.
>   (c) The patches extracted from the corresponding image, with the top
>   containing no manipulation and the bottom one containing some
>   manipulations. (d) Radon transform of two patches from the manipulated
>   and non-manipulated images. (e) Sum along the columns of the radon
>   transform. Here, we can see that the non-manipulated patch exhibits
>   high magnitude at the right of the curve, whereas low value is
>   observed in the same region for the manipulated patch. Differences
>   such as these are seen across other manipulated and non-manipulated
>   patches.

I have manipulated images but how can I get the results in (a) (b) (c) and (d)?
As mention in the paper, this figure is just an example of Randon and ground-truth mask

Comment: If you're a beginner, I suggest starting with something (a lot) simpler…

Comment: @martineau  I am not an abc beginner. I just started with ML and this figure does not use ML. as mentioned in the paper this is just an example of Randon.